# How to avoid sending mail in senders sent folder of gmail and sent in another folder

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I am using swift mailer to send mails. In senders sent Folder email is added.
How to avoid adding mail in sent folder and add them in another folder of gmail.

I have checked the imap_append function to copy mail in another folder, but in that case 2 mails are in sent folder and 2 mails in the 'xxxx' folder of gmail mailbox.
Is there any another way?

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use `imap_mail_move` to move message to another folder.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail-move.php